# Print another page, but stay on the current one

Tags: javascript, php, css, http

I have an invoice system made in PHP. There is a view with all customer's invoices. I'd like to make an option to print an invoice.

I know about `window.print()` and `media="print"` for CSS. But I was thinking, is it possible to just print an invoice by clicking a button next to it, but staying on the list page? It would just open a printing prompt with different content and do nothing to the current experience.

I thought of a workaround. On click, I could just replace contents of some element with invoice's data and make the styles hide everything else besides that container. That looks like a trick to me though. Is there any other solution to that problem? Perhaps something like `download` attribute for links:

```
<a href="invoice.php?id=3" download="invoice.html">Download Me</a>
```

That could be something like:

```
<a href="invoice.php?id=3" print>Print Me</a>
```

Or perhaps an HTTP header? Please share some advices.

Comment: specify a target perhaps?

Comment: You have to load the data into view or the client won't be aware of the data you want to print. That can be a new window or a frame or a modal or whatever... Then you need to use other methods to tell the client what to print and what not to and how it will look when printed.

Comment: @daddygames but it works for downloading as I mentioned, so it could be done in theory. The content could be loaded in the background and then prompt the printing. I don't think that's implemented though.

Comment: @charlietfl I think `iframe` can be a nicer workaround than mine. Just load a view to the invisible iframe and then do `window.print()` once it's loaded. I need to try it.

Comment: @charlietfl I wanted to avoid any window opening, because it's just ugly experience, I personally hate the immediately-closed-windows (or tabs).

Comment: I think you didn’t understand what I said.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use JQuery PrintJS plugin below:

http://printjs.crabbly.com/

This will ultimately solve your problem.

Comment: Looks promising. Do you know what is it doing behind the scenes?

Comment: For the PDF, it uses HTML iframe tag. Not sure about printing HTML.

Comment: I just did a test and I'm a little surprised. Printing works just fine if you just put `window.print()` in the destination file and then link it with `<a href="destination.html" target="my-iframe">`, where `my-iframe` is iframe's name. I didn't know it's possible to run scripts from an iframe that way.